# Display items on TableView - Newbie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a tableView.

In each cell i display the following characters `A`, `B`, `C` etc..

When a user clicks on `A` i need the page to go to the other view that shows another tableView that prints the following text `America`,
`Australia`. (This part has been done)

When the user clicks `B`,  The view goes to the other page, but since there are no countries stating with the character `B` it shows an
empty table.

When the user clicks on `C` countries `Canada` and `China` gets displayed.

What i want to do is, When the user clicked on `B` and since there aren't any countries, i don't want the page to get re-directed to-
another page that shows an empty table.

How should i solve this ?

****** All the Country names are loaded from sqlite

I have added the code as follows, so this is why all my screen get directed to the other view (and `B` showing an empty tableView)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


     Countries *viewControllerCountries = [[Countries alloc] initWithNibName:@"Countries" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerCountries animated:YES];

    [viewController release];

}
```

Comment: Illep,have u solved your problem ?

Comment: NO i haven't. If you have a solution please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a method in your Countries class to allow your parent view controller retrieves the record counts. If the count is 0 then don't push the view.

P.S. I think something like CountriesViewController is less confusing than Countries.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

    Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [Array1 addObject:@"A",@"B",@"C",nil];

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 Static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    cell=[tbView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

     if(tableView==self.tbView)
    {
         cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } 
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    return cell;
}
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 if(tableView==self.tbView)
    { 
        return [Array count];
    }
//when select the tableview cell want you want set codes here
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
}
```

Comment: `When the user clicks on B and since there aren't any countries, i don't want the page to get re-directed to- another page that shows an empty table.` <-- Still it doesn't explain this

Answer (score 0):

> -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
{
```

//code here
    }